# HighChart(highstock) load graph on some selectors not on others

Tags: highcharts

I created a highstock spline graph with half an hour interval data. The graph displays on "1 month,3 month" selectors, disappear on "all" selector. There are too many data points which could be the problem; but my other hourly dataset has even more data and works just fine.
See all the code in jsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/gbr1v9yu/8/

Here is my code for highchart:

```
$('#chart-A').highcharts('StockChart', {

    rangeSelector : {
        selected : 0
    },

    title : {
        text : 'Water Level'
    },
    // xAxis: {       
        // ordinal: false
    // },
   yAxis: {
       title:{text:'Water Level(m)'},
            labels: {
                align:'left',
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + ' m';
                }
            }
   },
    navigator : {
        enabled : false
    },
    colors: ['#0000FF'],
    series : [{
        type: 'spline',
        name : 'Water Level',
        data : tsData,

        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2,
            valueSuffix: 'm'
        }
    }]
});
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is caused by parsing nulls: `parseFloat(data[i][1])`. Since you already have numbers in the array, this is not necessary, see working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ggab6ah8/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Pawel! You really helped me out.